# Symfony 4.4.15 dependency-injection deprecation

Tags: php, dependency-injection, deprecated, symfony-4.4

I am updating my instance of Symfony to 4.4.15 and I have come across a deprecation that I can't make sense of. It is saying:

```
Since symfony/dependency-injection 5.1: Not setting the attribute "package" of the node "deprecated" in "/var/www/html/freestyle/Symfony/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Resources/config/web.xml" is deprecated.
```

I have looked online and cannot find anything that would help make sense of the issue or how to resolve it.

Any help in understanding it and how to go about correcting this deprecation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing that web.xml config file has a `<deprecated>` element which should have a `package` attribute? Not sure how that helps, though.

Comment: What I'd ask is... why is symfony/dependency-injection **5.1** being installed if you are updating to 4.4? In 4.4 that deprecation wouldn't even exist (yet) and will get sorted out as you update, so I wouldn't worry too much.